# How do you correspond indexes in 2 lists?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists below and I need the user to enter the coin type from the list which I was able to do. After the bag weight is asked, but whatever coin type was entered first has to match the index of the bag weight but I cannot seem to do this as the code I typed has an error

```
#this is the lists I am using 
coinType = [2, 1, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
bagWeight = [12, 8.75, 8, 5, 6.5, 3.25, 7.12, 3.56]

#allows user to input coin type
print('£2, £1, 50p, 20p, 10p, 5p, 2p, 1p')
print (coinType)
flag="t"
while flag=="t":
    coinType1 = int(input('enter your coin type: '))
    if coinType1 in coinType:
        flag="n"

#allows user to input bag weight
print('12g, 8.75g, 8g, 5g, 6.5, 3.25g, 7.12g, 3.56g')
print (bagWeight)
flag="t"
while flag=="t":
    bagWeight1 = float(input('enter your bag weight: '))
#here I am trying to say that when a bagweight index doesn't match the cointype index a while loop will keep aking until the indexes match
if (bagWeight1[])!= (coinType1[]):
    flag="t"
```

Comment: What is the exact error message and on what line is it occurring?

Comment: It looks like your second `while` loop has no exit condition, and the error looks like just a `SyntaxError` against the last `if` statement. So, with that in mind, do the bagweights and coinTypes correspond? i.e.: bagweight 12 goes *only* with cointype 2 in the first position?

Comment: Yes that is true

Comment: the error message is a syntax error

Comment: The syntax error is probably because you are trying to slice a float. `bagWeight[]` doesn't make any sense because `bagWeight` is a float not a list or array. (Even if it was a list you would need `[:]` for it to by syntactically okay).

Comment: Any reason why dictionary is not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the list `index()` method:

```
if coinType1 in coinType:
    coin_index = coinType.index(coinType1)
```

Then later you can check if the bagWeight has the right index.

```
if bagWeight1 in bagWeight:
    bag_index = bagWeight.index(bagWeight1)

if coin_index == bag_index:
    # Do Something
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this helped answer your question feel free to accept it as the answer by pressing the tick.

Answer (score 0):

The builtin [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) might be helpful here, since you don't have to explicitly match indices. This is, of course, assuming that the lists are designed to match index-by-index (the coin in the first position goes *only* with the weight in the first position)

```
types_weights = list(zip(coinType, bagWeight))
# [(2, 12), (1, 8.75)...]

coin_type = int(input("Pick a type"))

selections = [x for x in types_weights if x[0]==coin_type]

if not selections:
    raise ValueError("Wrong coin type!")

bag_weight = float(input("Pick a weight"))

selections = [x for x in selections if x[1]==bag_weight]

if not selections:
    raise ValueError("Wrong bag weight!")
```